# Eigendecomposition of $A^TD_iA$, with $A$ rectangular and $D_i$ diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms, svd

Given $A^TD_iA$, where:

- $A$ is a rectangular matrix
- $D_i$ is a diagonal matrix with positive entries
- $A^TD_iA$ is a positive definite matrix

I need to compute the eigendecompositions of $A^TD_iA$, where $i\in{1,...,N}$. Each $D_i$ is different. Is there a way to do all these eigendecompositions without doing it from scratch for each $i$?

Edit: In this problem, $D_i$ is given by

$$D_i:=\left(\left(\text{diag}(b-Ax_i)\right)^{2}\right)^{-1}$$

where $b$ is a fixed column vector, and $x_i$ is a column vector different for each $i$. The operator $\text{diag}(\cdot)$ takes a column vector and returns a diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are the elements of that vector.

Comment: First of all, it bears mentioning that in the case where $AA^T$ is diagonal (i.e. $A$ has orthogonal rows), this is very easy

Comment: Second, note that this is equivalent to computing the singular value decomposition of $\sqrt{D_i}A$. If $D_2$ is the same as $D_1$ except for one diagonal entry, then we can obtain the singular value decomposition of $\sqrt{D_2}A$ via a rank-1 update to the SVD of $\sqrt{D_1}A$. Some algorithms for doing this are discussed on [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/143375/34894).

Comment: It might also be helpful to note that the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A^TDA$ match the positive eigenvalues of 
$$
\pmatrix{0&A^T\sqrt{D}\\ \sqrt{D}A & 0} \text{ or }
\pmatrix{0&\sqrt{D}A\\ A^T\sqrt{D} & 0}
$$

Comment: If we want to minimize the number of entries of the matrix that depend on $D$, you could also use
$$
\pmatrix{0&A^T\\ DA & 0} \text{ or } \pmatrix{0&DA\\ A^T& 0}
$$
instead

Comment: Thanks, I have just added the definition of each $D_i$, in case the structure of this matrix could be exploited

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be $m \times n$, so $D$ is $m \times m$ and $A^T D A$ is $n \times n$. If $m \geq n$, I don't see any useful shortcuts.

If $m<n$, compute a $QR$-factorization $A = RQ$, so $Q$ is $n \times n$ orthogonal and $R$ is of the form $[R_0 \ 0]$ with $R_0$ an $m \times m$ lower triangular matrix. Then
$$A^T D A = Q^T R^T D R Q = Q^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} R_0^T D R_0 &0 \\ 0&0 \end{bmatrix} Q.$$
Conjugating by $Q$ doesn't change the eigenvalues, so the eigenvalues are the same as those of the middle matrix, meaning $n-m$ zeroes and the eigenvalues of $R_0^T D R_0$.

Computing the $QR$ factorization is a one time cost, where as the improvement from $A^T D_i A$ to $R_0^T D_i R_0$ happens for each $i$ so, if you have a lot of diagonal matrices, and $m \ll n$, I would expect this to be a good trade off.